# Compartment usage for POST/PUT

Tags: hl7-fhir

While a compartment representation is valid for searches (GET), is it incorrect to use the compartment based representation for POST/PUT interactions.

For instance -

GET [base]/Patient/[id]/Condition - this is the usage pattern mentioned for compartments (http://www.hl7.org/fhir/compartmentdefinition.html#use)

however, is this also correct -

POST/PUT [base]/Patient/[id]/Condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not presently supported.  Feel free to submit a change request if you'd like for such a feature to be considered.  (It's actually a good idea to submit a change request for clarification either way.)

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, I have submitted the same for clarification